# Can I make it to where my off screen menu works in all browsers?

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a site for school and things were going great. However, I attempted to open the site on different browsers and ran into a problem. In some browsers the off screen menu I made in html/css does not seem to want to work right. Sometimes it will appear on the screen and never close and sometimes the button I made will disappear and you can't access the menu at all. Is there a way to make it work across all browsers. I believe the error occurred in chrome and internet explorer as well as firefox. However it works right on my computer in all three browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Code Resources</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cisco.css" media="screen">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
  <figure>
    <img src="menubanner.jpg"  alt="menu banner" />
  </figure>
<ul>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="htmlcss.html">HTML & CSS</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="ciscohome.html">Cisco</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"></label>
<div class="site-wrap">
  <h1>Cisco Router and Switch Commands</h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Css is:

```
.navigation {
  /* critical sizing and position styles */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;

  /* non-critical appearance styles menu color */
  list-style: none;
  background: #333;
}

figure {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0;

}
figure img {
  width: 100px;
}
/* Navigation Menu - List items */
.nav-item {
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid #111;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.nav-item a {
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s, background 0.5s;
}
.nav-item a:hover {

  background: white;
  color: rgb(123,193,149);
}
/* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */
.site-wrap {
  /* Critical position and size styles */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: white; /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  padding: 4em;
  background-image: url(b1.gif);
  background-size: contain;
}
/* Nav Trigger */
.nav-trigger {
  /* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
  /* critical positioning styles */
  position: fixed;
  left: 15px; top: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* Menu Button*/
  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  height: 75px;
  width: 125px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("menubutton.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}

/* Make the Magic Happen */
.nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
  transition: left 0.2s;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
  left: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  left: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

body {
    /* Without this, the body has excess horizontal scroll when the menu is open */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Additional non-critical styles */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

code {
    padding: 2px;
    background: #ddd;
}

/* Micro reset */
*,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
  .nav-trigger,label {display:none;}
  .nav-item,figure {width:20%}
  .site-wrap {min-width:80%;float:right;}
  figure img {
  width: 150px;
}
}
```

Comment: Please JSFiddle it up

Comment: have you tried using http://modernizr.com/ ??

What browsers are you having problems with?

Comment: I am having problems with Mozilla Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer. It doesn't always work and it doesn't always fail to work and no I have never used JSfiddle or modernizr.com.

Answer (score 0):

in this section needed to change the min-width to 1600 px

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
  .nav-trigger,label {display:none;}
  .nav-item,figure {width:20%}
  .site-wrap {min-width:80%;float:right;}
  figure img {
  width: 150px;
}
}
```